# Lambda capture an array element failed

Tags: c++, gcc, lambda, language-lawyer, clang++

The following C++ code makes the compiler GCC(6.3.0) and Clang (3.8.0) mad.

```
for (auto v : vectors2d)
    for_each (begin(ret), end(ret), [v[3]] (int &n) { n+= v[3];});
```

While the following is fine

```
for (auto v : vectors2d) {
    auto val = v[3];
    for_each (begin(ret), end(ret), [val] (int &n) { n+= val;});
}
```

I know in C++ 14 I can do something like

```
for (auto v : vectors2d)
    for_each (begin(ret), end(ret), [val=v[3]] (int &n) { n+= val;});
```

The error in GCC is

```
expected identifier before '[' token
```

Clang says

```
expected ',' or ']' in lambda capture list
```

My question is: Why it is illegal for `[v[3]]` to appear in a capture list?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `[val=v[3]]` is legal since C++14.

Comment: You can also just capture the entire `v` by reference.

Comment: yes, val=v[3] is legall in C++14.

Comment: So what version are you asking about? C++11?

Comment: [v[3]] is illegal in all versions I think

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> My question is why it is illegal for `[v[3]]` in capture list?

As described in 5.1.2/1 [expr.prim.lambda] in N4141, the items in a capture list shall be either a *simple-capture* or an *init-capture*.

The former is any of

- *identifier*
- `&` *identifier*
- `this`,

the latter either *identifier initializer* or `&` *identifier initializer*.

`v[3]` fits none of the above and is thus correctly rejected by the compiler.

Comment: @gsamaras It's an identifier, followed by an initializer. Like `val=v[3]`, with `val` being the identifier and `=v[3]` being the initializer.

Answer (score 3):

`v[3]` is not a variable - it's a complex expression which unfolds to `*(v + 3)` (if `operator[]` is not overloaded). So, capturing `v[3]` is very similar in its spirit to capturing of `x * x + y * y` - and that makes much less sense. E.g. the compiler would have to accept `x * x + y * y` inside the lambda, but sometimes reject `y * y + x * x` because overloaded operators do not have to be commutative.

Basically, you ask compiler: "if I use an expression equivalent to what I captured, it's ok, but if I mix variables the other way around, you should give me compiler error".

Suppose `v[3]` was legal. Then all of the following lambdas should be compiled correctly:

```
[v[3]]() { return v[3]; }
[v[3]]() { return v[2 * 2 - 1]; }
[v[3]](int x) { assert(x == 3); return v[x]; }
```

So if we want "invalid capture" to be a compiler error, the compiler should be able to somehow "prove" that we're not going to access any element in `v` other than `v[3]`. This is harder than the halting problem, so it's impossible.

We could, of course, make some less strict limitations: e.g. allow only `v[3]`, but not `v[2 * 2 - 1]` or create some algorithm for detection of such cases that work "good enough", but sometimes provide false negatives. I don't think it's worth the effort - you can always "cache" the expression inside a variable and capture that by value.